# webRTC: getusermedia in qtwebkit2.3 is not working

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, webrtc, getusermedia

I am doing a project in qt in which new i am trying to enable webRTC in the fancy-browser. 
          I want to us QT4.8 for this so i have downloaded qtWebKit2.3 and i have build successfully by enabling media-stream. 
         But the problem is that when i am running a webpage which uses getusermedia it doesn't access my webcam. what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that WebRTC is currently not supported by qtwebkit.

Comment: i happened to see apost in [link](http://blogs.kde.org/2012/11/14/introducing-qtwebkit-23) regarding the webkit. The webkit in QT5 has mediastream(webrtc) module. Is there any way to integrate webrtc in qt4.8 such as using libjingle from google.

Answer (score 1):

The webrtc is not currently enabled in the qtwebkit of qt4.8 or 5 , But you can enable the same in QT5 using the google's **libjingle** library. I was almost successfull with getusermedia api...

Comment: Hey there, your answer sounds interesting. Can you elaborate a little? I am very new to Qt, I am not sure what you mean with "you can enable the same in QT5 using the google's libjingle library" and I am very interested. Thanks